# Difference between value from multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I would like to find the difference between the matched serial numbers from   multiple excel sheets
sheet 1

```
  June July
B  10   20
A  50   90
```

Sheet 2

```
  June  July
A 6     3
C 5     9
B 10    5
```

Sheet 3(results)

```
   June  July
A  44     87
B  0      15
```

Comment: Subtract one VLOOKUP from another.

Comment: sheet 3 should populate the result from sheet1 and sheet 2 by matching and then subtracting as shown in sheet3 results

Comment: i have tried vlookup but doesnt work, may be i dont know how to get the difference

Comment: `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:B,COLUMN(B:B),FALSE)-VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:B,COLUMN(B:B),FALSE)` put that in B2 on Sheet3 and copy over and down.